# How can I get File Save to show all types?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any global setting to get File Save to show files of all types? The 
filtering to just the current document type wastes more time here than it saves.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lTafi7d.png]

Comment: Pretty sure not. My experience programming those File dialogs is that the program that calls then is totally in charge of what options it gives. (Most programmers will add the All Files/*.* option as well, but not all it seems.)

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to **see all kinds of files** that are in your current folder, go to the file name box, type * (shift-8) and hit enter, all filetypes should appear.
- If you want to **save with a different file extention than the ones allowed** type your filename and preferred extension surrounded by quotes e.g. "readme.nfo"  As long as it's in quotes you won't get readme.nfo.txt

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't answer the question, but very useful info regardless.

Comment: Lemme see, you would like all programs, in their "save as" the window to have a drop-down menu of all possible filetypes? Even of another program? Or just a "all files" the option to always appear in the list?

Comment: "you would like all programs, in their "save as" the window to have a drop-down menu of all possible filetypes?" No. I would like all programs' Save As to SHOW files of all types. The drop-down can stay as it is.